# OCaml: Tree functions

Tags: module, ocaml, tree

Are there any modules or functions for dealing with trees? I have a type that looks like this:

```
type t =
  Leaf of string (* todo: replace with 'a *)
| Node of string * t list
```

I'm struggling to do insertion, removal of subtrees, etc.

I've used Google but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

Read the implementation of module Set in the sources of the OCaml standard library.
They are implemented with binary trees, only a little more sophisticated than yours.

(I would recommend you start with binary trees instead of having a list of children as you seem to have defined)

Comment: yeah, but I'm using these trees to do sentence syntax, so I can't just throw values in there. they need to maintain order, and I was hoping to establish this order just by creating the tree properly, although I guess I could use a wrapper type with both a number and the word itself...

Comment: You *can* establish the order by creating the tree properly.
Actually the module Set maintains the elements of the tree in order (lowest element in the leftmost descendant), so I still think it's a good source of inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

In the past, I've used [ocamlgraph](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/).
This is not a trivial lib to use, but if you need to insert nodes and change path, that could the trick, I've never used that in a b-tree context though...

And extracted from the language documentation:

> The most common usage of variant types
>   is to describe recursive data
>   structures. Consider for example the
>   type of binary trees:

```
#type 'a btree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree;;
type 'a btree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree
```

> This definition reads as follow: a
>   binary tree containing values of type
>   'a (an arbitrary type) is either
>   empty, or is a node containing one
>   value of type 'a and two subtrees
>   containing also values of type 'a,
>   that is, two 'a btree.
>
> Operations on binary trees are
>   naturally expressed as recursive
>   functions following the same structure
>   as the type definition itself. For
>   instance, here are functions
>   performing lookup and insertion in
>   ordered binary trees (elements
>   increase from left to right):

```
#let rec member x btree =
   match btree with
     Empty -> false
   | Node(y, left, right) ->
       if x = y then true else
       if x < y then member x left else member x right;;
val member : 'a -> 'a btree -> bool = <fun>

#let rec insert x btree =
   match btree with
     Empty -> Node(x, Empty, Empty)
   | Node(y, left, right) ->
       if x <= y then Node(y, insert x left, right)
                 else Node(y, left, insert x right);;
val insert : 'a -> 'a btree -> 'a btree = <fun>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Does Node have to be defined somewhere? I see you're using some sort of constructor for Node in insert, how does that work, and where is it implemented? Or is Node(x, left, right) just pattern matching? If so, can you explain the syntax for that a little more? Thanks, your post is very helpful.

Comment: In addition to @LB40 's answer here's remove: http://geck1.blogspot.com/2014/02/ocaml-review-day-4-binary-tree-ops.html